# Unable to run coverage tool using embedded python using the -m option or when copied to different path locations in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, embedded, code-coverage

I am trying to run the python coverage tool using embedded python downloaded from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/python-3.6.1-embed-amd64.zip
The following are the steps I followed to run a test code using coverage module.

1) After downloading python-3.6.1-embed-amd64.zip, I uncompress the files to D:\some_directory\python-3.6.1-embed-amd64

2) cd python-3.6.1-embed-amd64

3) python get-pip.py

4) python -mpip install coverage

5) python-3.6.1-embed-amd64\python36._pth is changed to

```
python36.zip
Lib\site-packages
.

# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site
```

6) In case if there is an internet proxy to used then use the following command

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy_ip:proxy_port
```

7) python -mpip install coverage

Create test files as follows

The file module_prog.py is as follows

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    Dummy method for testing
"""


def method_to_tested() -> None:
    """
    Method To be tested
    """
    print("Called method to be tested")
```

The file test_module.py is as follows

```
""" Unit test script for testing File : test_module.py
"""

import unittest
from module_prog import method_to_tested


class TestMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Testing the methods """

    def test_method_to_tested(self):
        method_to_tested()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

8) I run the following

```
D:\some_directory\python-3.6.1-embed-amd64>python test_module.py

Called method to be tested
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

9) But if I run the instruction as mentioned below using converage I get the following error.

```
D:\some_directory\python-3.6.1-embed-amd64>python -mcoverage run test_module.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_module.py", line 4, in <module>
    import unittest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unittest'
```

If I run the command

```
  Scripts\converage.exe run test_module.py
```

Then coverage run successfully,
But if I move the embedded python to another directory and try to run the same command as above then I get the following error

```
D:\some_other_directory\python-3.6.1-embed-amd64>Scripts\coverage.exe run test_module.py

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using 
'"d:\some_directory\python-3.6.1-embed-amd64\python.exe" "D:\some_other_directory\python-3.6.1-embed-amd64\Scripts\coverage.exe" run test_module.py'
```

How can I make coverage run as a python module